# Tabbar activity loads activity android orientation issue

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I have a tab bar activity that loads 2 activities as per the selected tab.I want to force portrait orientation to my first activity only but when I add "android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait" to my first activity it doesn't work. Then I add the same line to my tab bar activity what it does is it forces both the activities to be in portrait. I just want my first activity to be in portrait mode.Please help.Thanks

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this,Activity1.class);
 spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("dashboard").setIndicator("Over",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this,Activity2.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("settings").setIndicator("Set",
                      res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_ta))
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Comment: Post your tab bar code. generally its fragments and both fragments should ideally work in both modes

Comment: Activity1 and Activity2 should be a fragments not an activites.

Comment: Now i am using activities and not fragments.Please help

Comment: post  manifest and all three activities code